# git 2.34.1 dubious ownership error not fixed by safe.directory

Tags: git

Running Ubuntu 22.04 in an LXC. git version is 2.34.1. Installed a web application under the user 'brian' but none of the calls to `git` work (this works fine on an PiOS system - git 2.20.1).

I have found I am getting a return error of 128 and trying to run `git` commands from the command line as `www-data` user, result in the error

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at
```

From the announcement of 2.36 https://github.blog/2022-04-18-highlights-from-git-2-36/#stricter-repository-ownership-checks it look like this should be fixed by adding a `safe.directory` option.

However, I am running 2.34.1. I have tried to use this command

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

(with and without `sudo`) as the user brian, to no effect - the error continues.

I also tried it for the specific directory as well, with no success.

Any suggestions how to fix?

Comment: you need to execute the command as the user receiving the error (www-data)

Comment: Tried ` sudo -u www-data git config --global --add safe.directory '*'` and I get the error `error: could not lock config file /var/www/.gitconfig: Permission denied`

Comment: Maybe the '*' syntax is not supported in your version. Try adding the full path (as the command should be outputed by git in your error message)

Comment: User `www-data` does not have permission to update (or perhaps create, or both) "his" (its) own config file. You can do what you did (`--system`) if you're willing to disable all security for all users, or you can just create or update the `/var/www/.gitconfig` file by whoever it is that *does* have permission to create it. It's probably wisest to use the narrowest `safe.directory` setting possible: e.g., list *just* the directory or directories that should be considered safe.

Comment: @torek, I'll look into that. Would the `/.gitconfig/` be in the respective folders that have an associated Git Repository (there are an number and some are symlinked)? or is `/var/www/` considered the HOME directory for `www-data`?

Comment: The result you got implies the latter (that user `www-data` has `/var/www` set as its $HOME).

Comment: I have tried various combinations to try and limit the scope, none have worked. It also appears that it is not possible to add more than one entry, each `--add` simply overwrites the previous entry, even though the resulting config file seems to offer the ability to add multiple paths. My solution works even if it is not ideal in a wider deployment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer (for me currently) is to use `--system` rather than `--global`

This command worked on a fresh install (`sudo` if not `root`);

```
git config --system --add safe.directory '*'
```